# Webflux with reactive redis cache

Tags: java, redis, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a `CacheConfig` where I've setup the `ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory` and I can connect to Redis. However when I attempt to save anything into the cache it fails due to

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultSerializer.serialize(DefaultSerializer.java:43) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.Serializer.serializeToByteArray(Serializer.java:56) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:60) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
```

I think the problem is I can't serialize Flux/Mono objects so I've attempted to write a custom serializer to handle this by doing it manually myself, but I don't think I'm able to do that without calling `.block()` on `Flux` objects so I can get their contents into a `byte[]`.

My cache config:

```java
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CacheConfig implements CachingConfigurer {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
                .commandTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
                .shutdownTimeout(Duration.ZERO)
                .build();

        RedisStandaloneConfiguration serverConfig = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("localhost", 6379);

        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(serverConfig, clientConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfig = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
                .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new ReactiveRedisSerializer<>(objectMapper)));

        return RedisCacheManager.builder(redisConnectionFactory())
                .cacheDefaults(cacheConfig)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public CacheResolver cacheResolver() {
        return new SimpleCacheResolver(cacheManager());
    }
}
```

And the code I've got for the `ReactiveRedisSerializer` which you can see is blocking and will throw ``

```java
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ReactiveRedisSerializer<T> implements RedisSerializer<T> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
       @Override
    public byte[] serialize(T t) throws SerializationException {
        if (t == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (t instanceof Mono<?> mono) {
            try {
                return objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(mono.toFuture().get());
            } catch (JsonProcessingException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                throw new SerializationException("Failed to serialize Mono", e);
            }
        }

        if (t instanceof Flux<?> flux) {
            try {
                List<?> list = flux.collectList().block(); // How to avoid doing this?
                return objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(list);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                throw new SerializationException("Failed to serialize Flux", e);
            }
        }

        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(t).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new SerializationException("Failed to serialize object", e);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public T deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws SerializationException {
        if (bytes == null) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return (T) objectMapper.readValue(bytes, Object.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SerializationException("Failed to deserialize object", e);
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't feel like the right way to go, so is there a supported "out the box" approach here?

Edit:

I'm adding data to the cache in the very standard Spring way

```java
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "placesCache")
public Flux<Place> getPlaces(final PlaceRequest placeRequest) {

    final String query = "%s in %s".formatted(placeRequest.vendorType(), placeRequest.city());

    return googleMapsService
            .textSearch(query)
            .flatMapMany(response -> placeMapper.toPlaces(response)
                    .map(place -> place.withQuery(query).withVendorType(placeRequest.vendorType())));
}
```

Nothing special about this.

Comment: It's definitely a wrong way because it breaks Reactor flow. Can you show a part of the code related to the caching itself?

Comment: I've updated the question, if I understood you correctly. I'm just doing a standard `@Cacheable` on the service class

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess `@Cacheable` doesn't support Reactor yet. There are some discussions like https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/17920 but to my understanding there is no standard way yet an you have to implement caching part manually not relying on `@Cacheable`